# How to log ffmpeg process to file using background terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, terminal

I'm facing a big misunderstanding with bash.

Executing line

```
ffmpeg -y -i "file.mp4" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy "file.mkv" 2> output.log
```

process is logged to the file.

---

But executing

```
xfce4-terminal -e "ffmpeg -y -i \"file.mp4\" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy \"file.mkv\"" 2> /home/$(whoami)/Desktop/output.log"
```

the logging to file doesn't work.

---

What could cause this issue?

Comment: You're redirecting the output of `xfce4-terminal`, not `ffmpeg`'s output

Comment: I also tried this: xfce4-terminal -e "ffmpeg -y -i \"file.mp4\" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy \"file.mkv\" 2> /home/$(whoami)/Desktop/output.log" but this time terminal suddenly exits without showing anything.

Comment: The redirection needs to happen inside the quotes; but running the command in a new terminal seems like a complication which you can easily get rid of and thus simplify your problem and your computing experience significantly. Once you figure out how to examine a log file from any terminal, you don't want or need to add new terminal windows for every program you run. You need to redirect both stdout and stderr, like `>output.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

It can get tricky escaping things when passing a script to a terminal. I would recommend putting your ffmpeg command into a file (e.g. `your-file.sh`, making it executable (by running `chmod +x your-file.sh`), then telling the terminal to run that file.

Comment: tried xfce4-terminal -e "ffmpeg -y -i \"file.mp4\" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy \"file.mkv\"" inside chmoded sh file and executed. Executing sh file in bash terminal with parameter 1>&file internally in sh file or externally appending in bash makes no difference.

Comment: Oh, I was talking about putting the ffmpeg command into a .sh file, then running the .sh file from the xfce4-terminal command. So you'd be running xfce4-terminal -e script.sh. Then you can break up your debugging into two parts: 1) make sure your script runs correctly when run directly (e.g. by running ./script.sh), then 2) make sure xfce4-terminal is launching and running the script correctly. If the script is exiting immediately, stick a sleep 10000 at the end of the script. Heck, you could even try that with your original command: xfce4-terminal -e "ffmpeg command ........; sleep 10000"

Comment: I already made things even more complicated! I just run ffmpeg without any nohup and xfce4-terminal and appended 2>&1 & and all just worked fine. The main reason for this was all ffmpeg operations in new terminal window with process logging to file. But obviously this doesn't work that way. But instead this can be done in sh's first line run ffmpeg to background and in next line open new terminal with while condition catting and grepping log file. :D

Comment: I don't know if I totally understand your use case, but it sounds like you've gotten it working? Yay!

Comment: absolutely! :))

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found one solution to my problem by adding `nohup` before ffmpeg like this:

`xfce4-terminal -e "nohup ffmpeg -y -i \"file.mp4\" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy \"file.mkv\""`

At least this stores me all terminal output data to /home/$(whoami)/nohup.out file.
Thanks anybody for trying to help me! :)